# Display base64 image based on condition / category

Tags: php, wordpress, svg, base64

I am trying to add a base64/SVG image over a DIV depending the kind of post I have on Wordpress. If it's a video it shows a play icon, if it's an audio, it shows a headphone icon.

Here's the code:

```
    if ( in_category ( 'video' )) {
        $mediaPlay = "PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxMDkuMTI2IDEwOS4xMjYiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik05OC45IDQ3LjY2M0wxOC4xOTggMS4wNjhjLTIuNDY3LTEuNDI0LTUuNTAyLTEuNDI0LTcuOTcyIDBDNy43NjIgMi40OSA2LjI0MyA1LjEyNCA2LjI0MyA3Ljk3djkzLjE5YzAgMi44NDcgMS41MjIgNS40NzggMy45ODIgNi45IDEuMjM2LjcxMiAyLjYxIDEuMDY2IDMuOTg2IDEuMDY2IDEuMzc3IDAgMi43NTQtLjM1NCAzLjk4Ni0xLjA2N0w5OC45IDYxLjQ2MmMyLjQ2NS0xLjQyMiAzLjk4My00LjA1NCAzLjk4My02LjkuMDA1LTIuODQ2LTEuNTE2LTUuNDc3LTMuOTgtNi45MDJ6IiBmaWxsPSIjRkZGIi8+PC9zdmc+";

    } elseif ( in_category ( 'audio' )) {
        $mediaPlay = "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";

    } else {
        $mediaPlay = "";
    }
```

The HTML that should make the image appear is this:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,<?php echo $mediaPlay; ?>">
```

The problem is that this conditioning thing just doesn't work. The way it is, it shows a broken image, just because it doesn't add the base64 code where it should.

If I just try this, without conditions, like:

```
$mediaPlay = "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";
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,<?php echo $mediaPlay; ?>">
```

It works, and I have no idea why.

How can I work this out?

Thank you. :)

Comment: "*just because it doesn't add the base64 code where it should.*" and where exactly is this added?

Comment: Did you want to check this 'video' and 'audio' inside archive page?

Comment: given that the plain case without any condition works, I would assume that it always goes into the final else, where mediaPlay is assigned empty and that would be the place to check. Add some stupid svg in the else branch ...